# Where did the bower-angular-bootstrap3 repository move to?

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, bower

I am getting a page not found error when trying to access the bower-angular-bootstrap3 repository: https://github.com/paptamas/bower-angular-bootstrap3.git/

Error message: 
bower ECMDERR       Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads ", exit code of #128

Additional error details:
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/paptamas/bower-angular-bootstrap3.git/' no
t found

Did the repository location change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the repository has been deleted from Github - infact the complete user profile has been deleted (https://github.com/search?q=paptamas)

Some search on Github seems the closed match would be: https://github.com/praneybehl/bower-angular-bootstrap3 - which seems to be just at fork of Angular UI Bootstrap. That project has a contributer called "tamaspap" which is really close to "paptamas" :-)

But in the end I would suggest using angular-generator (https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) and add Angular UI Bootstrap (https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap).
This is the official and it has been based of bootstrap 3 for quite some time now.